# sending an SMS from the ProximityIntentReceiver

Tags: android

programmers.Iam doing a Proximity Alert App and would like to know how to send an SMS from the ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver i.e autosends an SMS on entering a specific radius.

Below is my ProximityIntentReceiver  code,where can I place the SMS activity?

```
package jacojunga.retaildistributortrack;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;
String sender;
IntentFilter intentFilter;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

    Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

    if (entering) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "entering");
        Toast.makeText(context,sender ,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                                                                               (NotificationManager)                                                                                             context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent =   PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, null, 0);

                Notification notification = createNotification();
                notification.setLatestEventInfo(context,     "Proximity Alert!", "You are near your point of interest.", pendingIntent);

                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,  notification);
    } else {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "exiting");
       }

         }

        private Notification createNotification() {
    Notification notification = new Notification();

    notification.icon = R.drawable.pushpin;
    notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

    notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
    notification.ledOnMS = 1500;
    notification.ledOffMS = 1500;

    return notification;
       }

  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code to send SMS using broadcast reciever is

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, body, null, null);
```

You will also need to add this to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Place this when you get a proximity alert.

Comment: Many thanks....how about the phoneNumber.I intend to retrieve it from another activity.Any idea?

Comment: Yes, you can use phonenumber as a static and access directly or use argument passing through Intents. Let me know if you need more help on this.

Comment: It worked!!Am very grateful,friend...i also want the ProximityIntentReceiver to be always running and to Toast appropriately in the activity of context...currently it's only responding when the activity that called it is started...i need the receiver and activity that registers it to be running throughout the entire application...in case you know how

Comment: Not exactly sure, post another question so tha others might help